# Exchange '03 Remote Office Shared Calendar Speeds

Tags: exchange-2003, remote-access

I am looking for suggestions to improve shared calendar access speeds for a remote office connected to an Exchange server over VPN. The connection is a T1 but due to distance (Asia <-> North America) the speed to open a shared calendar can become very problematic (45s - 1.5m+). The office has 10 people.

Assuming there's no magic button to eliminate latency from Exchange we were hoping to find a way to replicate calendars to a local server or cache, like DFS for calendars (or something similar). Remote Desktop is out, however, as the speeds aren't that great either but mostly because organizationally no one wants to transition to RDP. That said, any information anyone can provide would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to this issue was to upgrade to Outlook 2007 in Cached mode. This allowed the shared calendar resources to be cached locally which dramatically improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the slowness is likely a combination of the connection and the info in this link:

http://blogs.technet.com/gerod_serafin/archive/2005/05/20/405229.aspx